# Unsatisfied Dependency Error through field in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

below code is working fine but if i comment the jdbcTemplateRandomName method in OracleConfiguration class i get the below error : -

I am trying to understand why i am getting the error by commenting jdbcTemplateRandomName method
Error is in BaseDaoImpl class.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'baseDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
@Component
    public class BaseDaoImpl {

        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


            public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
                                return jdbcTemplate;
            }
@Configuration   
 public class OracleConfiguration {

        @Bean
        DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            //removed code for brevity setting username,password to datasource
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
         public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateRandomName(DataSource dataSource) {
           JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
           jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
            return jdbcTemplate;
        }

    public class RolesDaoImpl  extends BaseDaoImpl implements RolesDao  {

    //removed lot of unnecessary  code for the question
    List<Roles> rolesList  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Roles>(Roles.class));
```

Comment: Is your `OracleConfiguration` class annotated with `@Configuration`?

Comment: Hello Chryllis.Yes it is .I will add @Configuration in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment `jdbcTemplateRandomName()` method you will remove declaration of `JdbcTemplate` bean from your Spring IoC configuration. So Spring will not be able to find suitable object to populate `jdbcTemplate` property of your `BaseDaoImpl` class

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Did you read the question carefully ?My jdbcTemplateRandomName()  method is fine .But when i comment this method i get an error in BaseDaoImpl  when in reality im making no reference of jdbcTemplateRandomName() in  BaseDaoImpl  .

Comment: i want to know how  my BaseDaoImpl.getJdbcTemplate() is getting initialized

Comment: @RajR `BaseDaoImpl` has property `jdbcTemplate` annotated with `@Autowired`. With this annotation you **ask** Spring IoC to look for an object of type `JdbcTemplate` in its configuration and set to that property. And this is method `jdbcTemplateRandomName()` which tells Spring IoC how to create object of type `JdbcTemplate`. When you comment out that method Spring no longer knows how to create object of type `JdbcTemplate` for you and throws exception.

Comment: thanks for the explanation .This explains the behavior. Even i was suspecting the same .